# Question about checkbox on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing a website for my University and I got a problem.

There is a page where I have the list of all students of the university. The admin can select some students that will be able to go to a selective process and then he have to see them in other separate page.

How can I do that using Ruby On Rails?

Thanks,

Hugo Henley

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you want use checkboxes you should write inside your form something similar to `<td><%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", "#{user.id}", true%><%= user.name%></td>` then you'll get array od user ids as an `params[:user_ids]` and you may show only this users on other page

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>in your view </h1>

By checking those ones using checkboxes you can get the id's of those students like this
<%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", "#{user.id}", true%>
```

passing those id's into the respective controller action

```
@users = User.where(:id => params[:user_ids])

Display those object details in to the required webpage using @users.each 
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<%end%>
```